# Loading image saved locally in Xamarin?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have made a method to save a Bitmap image fetched from a CDN to local storage. Find code below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to store the bitmap image fetched from the CDN locally.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool StoreDownloadedImageLocally(Bitmap image, string extension)
    {
        try
        {
            var directoryPath = absolutePath;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, extension + ".png");

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

I now need to create a method so that I can fetch the image I have just saved. The app needs to be able to display images offline, hence storing them locally once downloaded. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply load it with a Bitmapfactory

```
string inputPicturePath = "hello.jpg";
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
options.InSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile ( inputPicturePath, options);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, although I ended up using a stream to just read all bytes. Cheers though!